# I am trying to run a cronjob but it is not executing correctly

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have the following line in my crontab

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/screen -S lftp /bin/bash /media/c419d280-9833-4432-b5a5-520f040b87ec/NASDataDisk1/Other/autolftp-sftp.sh >> /media/c419d280-9833-4432-b5a5-520f040b87ec/NASDataDisk1/Other/sync_cron$
```

But for some reason I cannot get this to properly execute. My output file, sync_cron.log, reads 'Must be connected to a terminal.'

If I use the command

```
screen -S lftp bash autolftp-sftp.sh
```

it does execute correctly, so wouldn't the cronjob be doing essentially the same thing? But why is it not running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is with the latter part of the script when you are writing stdout to the file. It somehow kills the seesion i believe.

Can you try with parameters -d -m to screen.

Comment: Awesome, adding the -dmS parameters to screen appears to have fixed it. Thank you so much for your quick and useful answer.